# how to replace content of a column with values from another 3 columns?

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file like this:

```
$ head 1kG_MDS6.bim
1   rs2073813   0   753541  A   G
1   rs60320384  0   769223  G   C
2   rs59066358  0   771967  A   G
2   rs1055606   0   778745  G   A
3   rs6594026   0   782981  T   C
...
```

I would like to change the 2nd columns so that the output file looks like this:

```
1   1:753541:G:A 0  753541  A   G
1   1:769223:C:G 0  769223  G   C
2   2:771967:G:A 0  771967  A   G
2   2:778745:A:G 0  778745  G   A
3   3:782981:C:T 0  782981  T   C
...
```

so it would be replacing the 2nd column with is V1:V4:V6:V5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
awk '{$2 = $1":"$4":"$6":"$5 ; print }'
```

fields in awk can be set.